# MVC 4 Mobile Detection Not same for view as it is for layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am having a very strange issue. What makes it worse is that it ONLY happens in production (azure), not in the dev machine.

I am seeing my app use the .Mobile version of the layout but uses the desktop (not the .mobile) version of the view. I am completely lost as to how i would even solve this..

It is detecting the mobile version yet it's not... Any ideas?

Comment: also, it ONLY does this on the home page.. all other pages use the .mobile version of the view when it should..

Comment: I have exactly this issue. My staging machine renders the mobile view for the default route / , but the prod machine doesn't. On prod, though, I can browse to /home and it will work. Rebooting prod fixes it for [some period of time].

Comment: I resorted to writing an if, then in the controller to do the mobile view when it should. A workaround but I have not yet solved the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

The engine uses the files located here - `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers`

(Or `\Framework64\`)

They are probably different on either machine. Use Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice to find out which devices detect what. Also writing custom display modes could help?

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/09/18/asp-net-mvc-4-display-modes.aspx

Comment: that's funny cause the workaround i mentioned above uses Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice to manually put the correct view.. SO... that's not the issue :)

Comment: Have you checked the browser files on both servers? Have you tried custom display modes? If not then "that's not the issue" makes literally no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the solution I gave below was the answer (it worked for a brief moment), but it still switched to the wrong view after a while.

Like the rest of the internet, I installed [51 Degrees from Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/51Degrees.mobi)
This is working perfectly, and is very easy to set up

---

(The below doesn't work for me, but maybe it does for you)
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes

Looks like it is a known bug: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/280?PendingVoteId=280

According to codeplex link above, remember to make sure of this :

> For a small set of projects that customize the list of registered view
>   engines (for example, in Global.asax) you should make sure that you
>   are referencing Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedRazorViewEngine or
>   Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedWebFormViewEngine, instead of the classes that
>   ship in the core runtime binary